# VB.NET DataSet doesn't clear

Tags: mysql, vb.net, dataset

I'm using the MYSQL .NET connector with an adapter to fill a dataset from a SELECT statement. Between different SELECT statements I use the DataSet.Clear() function. The Getxml shows me that the dataset is empty, however when cycling through the Table's columns, I have all the columns from all the tables used in prior SELECT statements.

How do I go about that without Dimming new Datasets for each table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the DataTables from the DataSet as so:

```
ds.Tables.Clear();
```

This will remove the `DataTable`s in the collection. `DataSet.Clear()` removes the **rows** from all the DataTables in the DataSet

Comment: It did it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Theveloper look at my answer again. I updated it a millisec ago.

Comment: So I don't need to use DataSet.Clear() if I use DataSet.Tables.Clear() correct?

Comment: @Theveloper Correct. DataSet.Clear() will remove datatables (schema and data) from the DataSet.Tables collection. DataSet.Clear() will only remove the data from all the DataTables in the collection but will leave the schema (column definitions of the DataTables)